# Finding and copying a range of data between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, find, copy

I've been working on this code for a while and any help is appreciated!

I want to be able to put a known string on the open excel sheet `"B7"` and file location in `"B6"`. Using these inputs I want to open the other file, look for `"B7"` value (header for data table), and copy all of the data in that column and then return to workbook 1 to paste it.

I think my find function is working but the macro returns whatever column below whatever cell was already selected upon opening workbook 2.

```
Sub FindB7()

    Dim Look As Range
    Dim Sh As Worksheet

    Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    Range("H1") = Range("B6")
    Goal = Range("B7").Value

    Range("B6").Select
    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True

    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With Sh.UsedRange
            Set Look = .Cells.Find(What:=Goal)
            If Not Look Is Nothing Then
                adrs = Range(Look.Address).Select
                Data = Range(adrs, Selection.End(xlDown))
                ActiveWindow.Close
            Else
                Data = "Not Found"
            End If
        End With
    Next

    'paste data in original WkBk

    Range("H2").Value = Look
    Range("H3:H1000").Value = Data

'now remove all "extra" data

Cells.Replace What:="#N/A", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Just an (important) note: See [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to clean up the code, and also note that any time you use `Range` or `Cells` you should qualify the workbook/worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is to low to comment but I am able to give an answer, I do have an idea. You are looping through all the sheets, but with the first range declarations no sheet is given, so for example changing Columns("H:H") to Sheet("Sheet1").Column("H:H") might prevent referring to column H on the wrong sheet.